# How should I access the asset_url helper in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

When I try to use asset_url in my view (Rails 3.2), I get a NoMethodError.
What do have to do to be able to use AssetUrlHelper's methods in my views?

To explain this a bit better and maybe find an alternative solutions: I need to get an "asset link" to file attachments created with carrierwave.
My model has an attachment which points to a file in my assets directory. I need to draw a link to this file.

= link_to model.name, model.attachment(:size) 
gives me /myfiles/model/id/attachment/size.png (which is what is persisted by carrierwave)

= image_tag model.attachment(:size) 
gives me the wanted http://static_host.com/.../size.png

but I have no need for an image tag, but the plain link to the file at the asset host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works ok for me:

```
<%= link_to "link to asset", asset_path(article.image.url) %>
```

I'm using paperclip but I doubt it makes much difference

Answer (score 0):

I think the helper `asset_path` belongs to asset files (like `.css` and `.js`) , not views. In views is proper to be used helpers like `image_tag` or `stylesheet_include_tag`. This is the idea behind the asset-pipeline - to ease reference to assets.

Comment: Still, it should be possible to pull this functionality into my views somehow - as I do have this need...

Comment: You say `asset_url` , I've seen `asset_path` , which one is Pink ;)

Comment: In fact , the [helper's name](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html) is `asset_tag` (the one usable in a view).

Comment: undefined method `asset_tag' => :bad_luck